# How to Add objects to an immutable generic List using Select() Extension Method

Tags: c#, list, select, extension-methods, immutability

I have a immutable List.

In the below g.Select(...) I do a .ToList() which is put into the MemberIdList. I do not want to create a new List with ToList() rather I want to add each r.Field string to the immutable List inside the unit object.

How can I do this?

```
var groupedCollection = table.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => new
        {
            UType = row.Field<string>("UnitType"),
            UZoom = row.Field<string>("UnitZoom"),
            MZoom = row.Field<string>("MemberZoom"),
        });

    var unitCollection = groupedCollection
        .Select(g => new Unit
        {
            UnitType = g.Key.UType,
            UnitZoom = g.Key.UZoom,
            MemberZoom = g.Key.MZoom,
            MemberIdList = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("TestId")).ToList(),
        });

    List<Unit> units = unitCollection.ToList();


public class Unit
{
    public Unit()
    {
        MemberIdList = new List<String>();
    }

    public String UnitType { get; set; }
    public String UnitZoom { get; set; }
    public String MemberZoom { get; set; }
    public int MemberOrder { get; set; }

    public List<String> MemberIdList { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: In my context MemberIdList.AddRange(g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("TestId"))); does not work. Typing MemberIdList. there is no AddRange.

Comment: @msfanboy are you sure it is a `List<T>` then? As that definitely has AddRange. You will of course need to tell it the instance, I.e. Obj.MemberIdList.AddRange()

Comment: Btw ; `List<T>` is never immutable. A list-property without a setter is very different to an immutable list.

Comment: but I have a private setter??

Comment: @msfanboy so? that just means you can't change it to a **different** list. I can still call yourList.Add(x) - the *list* is not internally immutable.

Comment: ok then I had a wrong understanding of the term immmutable. Thanks for clarifying that Marc! Gave you a point! :)

Comment: @msfanboy nah, comment votes don't give points ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a constructor for Unit that takes the data for MemberIdList like:

```
public Unit(IEnumerable<string> memberIdList)
{
    MemberIdList = new List<string>(memberIdList);
}
```

and modify your select to:

```
.Select(g => new Unit(g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("TestId")))
{
    UnitType = g.Key.UType,
    UnitZoom = g.Key.UZoom,
    MemberZoom = g.Key.MZoom
});
```